# A question about the index of vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

$M$ is the boundary of a compact manifold $U$: $M = \partial{U}$, $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector field on $M$, how to prove that if $\mathbf{v}$ can be extended to be a nonvanishing vector field on all of the interior region $U$, then $\operatorname{index}(\mathbf{v})=0$?

Comment: Your question is ill-formed.  It looks like you want to ask about something related to the Poincare-Hopf index theorem, but for manifolds with boundary.  But when you refer to the "index" you do not supply any real context.  Which index are you talking about?

Comment: @RyanBudney Should I say the Brouwer degree of $\mathbf{v}$? It is the degree of map that maps $M$ onto a sphere of the same dimension defined by $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: Oh now I see. Your map $v$ is of the form $v : \partial U \to S^k$ and it extends to a map $v : U \to S^k$ is that correct? I assume $k$ is the dimension of $\partial U$.

Comment: @RyanBudney exactly.

Comment: What tools are you working with?  Homology/cohomology/poincare duality, or are you working with transversality?   There are approaches to your question from both directions.

Comment: @RyanBudney I think I know how to do it now, since $\mathbf{v}$ can be extended to a nonvanishing vector field on $U$, $\mathbf{v}$ on $M$ can be shrunk continuously into small sphere around any point in $U$, where vector field $\mathbf{v}$ behaves like a constant vector field and has index 0, so the original vector field on $M$ should have index 0. Is this correct? Is this homology?

Comment: Yes, an argument like that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{v}$ can be extended to a nonvanishing vector field on $U$, $\mathbf{v}$ on $M$ can be shrunk continuously into small sphere around any point in U, where vector field v behaves like a constant vector field and has index 0, so the original vector field on M should have index 0.